# Asp.Net Core Identity - Using a stored procedure to save new users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I see a lot of information on ASP.Net Core Identity and have been piecing together how to customize it, since I am building a site for use against an existing SQL Server database.

I have been able to customize my replacement for the `AspNetUsers` table, and have new users saving properly. Since in the existing systems that use this database there are a couple of stored procedure calls that happen that wrap a lot of functionality, I would like to use the same approach. So I think that instead of the default call like this:

```
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

I would need something that can call one or more stored procedures to create the user. Should I inherit from `UserManager` and override the `CreateAsync` call?  If so, can I use my existing user store? I'm a little fuzzy on what this looks like, WRT identity. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should keep using `_userManager.CreateAsync`, but configure it in such a way that your own implementation of a `UserStore` is used.

In `Startup.cs`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddIdentity<MyUser>()
        .AddUserStore<MyUserStore>();
}
```

Then, create a custom `UserStore`, where you can call your context class (including calls to stored procedures):

```cs
public class MyUserStore : IUserStore<MyUser>
{
    private MyContext _db;
    public MyUserStore(MyContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public async Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(MyUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // simply store entity in DB
        user = _db.Users.Add(user).Entity;
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

        // or run stored procedure
        await _db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("usp_MyUserCreationStoredProcedure @p0, @p1", user.FirstName, user.LastName);

        return IdentityResult.Success;
    }
}
```

You can check the relevant documentation on [how to create custom user stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers) for more information.

Comment: I will try this out today, I suspect that it will do what I want it to, combined with the suggestion of @twinmind to split out the actual insert from the proc, and perform both of your suggestions above, instead of either or.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider keeping Identity functions calls as is and adding application specific calls separately. CreateAsync does quite a lot of good things like password hashing, time stamping and user name/email normalization. This functionality is the actual valuable part of Identity product, and rewriting it would only introduce security vulnerabilities and will require substantial time otherwise used for application development. Identity is not just SQL tables, but also all the logic managing authentication workflows with implemented security best practices.

Comment: This makes sense, but doesn't something like @Metoule's suggestion below keep that intact?  I think that I can make it so that the proc does everything but the insert, and let Identity / CreateAsync handle that.  I agree that is different than my original question, but in light of what I see below and your comment I am inclined to go that route.

Comment: yes, @Metoule's approach looks solid. We can also consider wrapping user creation and procedure call into the same transaction to avoid data corruption during user creation